# "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer", while login to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, pem

When I am trying to login to my aws instance using ubuntu terminal, it says "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" after few seconds and the website which is hosted on the server is also not opening. I have never faced this kind of problem before. Please someone help.

This is the command I am using:-

```
ssh -i *****.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Comment: Is the server running? Does it display any status check warnings in the EC2 console? Has the server's address changed?  What about the CPU usage? Is it a T2 server, and if so are the CPU credits used up?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should check on [unix.se] or [su] instead of here. This is a pretty common question. Searching for that error message will yield dozens of other questions on the exact same subject.

Answer (score -2):

Although the documentation says that the username should be "ubuntu", in my experience "ec2-user" has been the username I've had to use with some Ubuntu AMI's in the past.

If this anomaly is effecting your instance than changing your login username to ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx should do the trick.

Comment: This won't solve the problem which the OP described. At the "ssh_exchange_identification" point of the SSH protocol, the remote server has no idea what user name you're trying to log in as.

Comment: I got the same error and changing to ec2-user solved my issue.